# Swap rows when conditions match for a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

```
user_id  event_name   event_params
10           start          /pseudo
10          subcategory      /home
10        add_basket_click   /click
10       add_basket_error    /event
10            end            /end
11           start           /pseudo
11      add_basket_click    /click
11       add_basket_error   /event
```

I want to swap rows for event_name, add_basket_click & add_basket_error. Currently add_basket_error comes after add_basket_click, I want it come before it. Output should like below. The real dataset has 10 million rows, so looking for a pythonic answer.

```
user_id event_name  event_params
10           start        /pseudo
10        subcategory       /home
10       add_basket_error   /event
10       add_basket_click   /click
10            end           /end
11           start         /pseudo
11        add_basket_error  /event
11       add_basket_click   /click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and it worked

```
df['scounter'] = df.groupby('user_id').cumcount()+1

#
df1 = df[df.event_name == 'Add_Basket_Error']
df = df[df.event_name != 'Add_Basket_Error']

#
df1['scounter'] = df1['scounter'] - 1.1

#
df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

#
df.sort_values(['user_id', 'scounter'], ascending = [True, True], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is possible create list of all possible values in `event_name` by expected order, then convert column to [ordered categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html), so possible sorting by 2 columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
L = ['start','subcategory','add_basket_error','add_basket_click','end']
df['event_name'] = pd.Categorical(df['event_name'], ordered=True, categories=L)
df = df.sort_values(['user_id','event_name'])

print (df)
   user_id        event_name event_params
0       10             start      /pseudo
1       10       subcategory        /home
3       10  add_basket_error       /event
2       10  add_basket_click       /click
4       10               end         /end
5       11             start      /pseudo
7       11  add_basket_error       /event
6       11  add_basket_click       /click
```

EDIT:

```
#added separate row 1 - not changed in output
print (df)
   user_id        event_name event_params
0       10             start      /pseudo
1       10  add_basket_error       /event
2       10       subcategory        /home
3       10  add_basket_click       /click
4       10  add_basket_error       /event
5       10               end         /end
6       11             start      /pseudo
7       11  add_basket_click       /click
8       11  add_basket_error       /event
```

You can compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and also [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values, last assign back swapped rows:

```
m11 = df['event_name'].eq('add_basket_click')
m12 = df['event_name'].shift(-1).eq('add_basket_error')

m21 = df['event_name'].eq('add_basket_error')
m22 = df['event_name'].shift().eq('add_basket_click')


df[m21 & m22], df[m11 & m12] = df[m11 & m12].values, df[m21 & m22].values
print (df)
   user_id        event_name event_params
0       10             start      /pseudo
1       10  add_basket_error       /event
2       10       subcategory        /home
3       10  add_basket_error       /event
4       10  add_basket_click       /click
5       10               end         /end
6       11             start      /pseudo
7       11  add_basket_error       /event
8       11  add_basket_click       /click
```

Comment: there would be many other event_names, I dont want to move them..just want to change positions of add_basket_click & add_basket_error.

Comment: @NK09 - There are only one `add_basket_error` an one `add_basket_click` per users? What is `print (df['event_name']).unique()`

Comment: psuedo_App_start', 'screen_view', 'add_basket_click', 'notification_receive', 'psuedo_App_start_2', 'notification_dismiss', 'Basket_Viewed', 'Basket_Rest_of_the_week', 'remove_basket_click', 'product_search', 'product_detail_click', 'subcategory_click', 'banner_click', 'Add_Basket_Error', 'Payment_Start', 'Payment_Success', 'category_click', 'Shopping_Credits', 'notification_open', 'Referral_Start', 'Invite_Code_Popup_Viewed', 'Invite_Code_Popup_Description'

Comment: Sign_up_Splash_Screen_Viewed', 'Edit_Recurring', 'Set_Recurring',
       'Referal_Success', 'Signup_Start', 'notification_foreground',
       'app_remove', 'Signup_Society_PageView', 'Payment_Failure',
       'Referral_Copy', 'Signup_Society_Selected',
       'Sign_up_Mobile_No_entry', 'Invite_Code_Details', 'Sign_up_City',
       'society_search'

Comment: @NK09 - It is too much :(

Comment: @NK09 - One thing - do you need swap only if `add_basket_error` is after `add_basket_click` ? There is no another row between?

Comment: add_basket_error is always after add_basket_click... there is no row in between

Comment: @NK09 - Supeeer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one potential solution, using `boolean indexing` and `loc`:

```
# Boolean series of event_name containing 'add_basket_error'
s = df.event_name.str.contains('add_basket_error')

# Create 2 frames, errors and events from boolean index 's'
errors, events = (df.loc[s[s].index].copy(), df.loc[s[s].index - 1].copy())

# Swap event and error values 
df.loc[s[s].index] = events.values
df.loc[s[s].index - 1] = errors.values
print(df)
```

[output]

```
   user_id        event_name event_params
0       10             start      /pseudo
1       10       subcategory        /home
2       10  add_basket_error       /event
3       10  add_basket_click       /click
4       10               end         /end
5       11             start      /pseudo
6       11  add_basket_error       /event
7       11  add_basket_click       /click
```